# How to find how much the mobile screen went from the eye's straight line

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have this requirement how to find whether the user is looking down or up the iPhone screen. like if the user have his iPhone in desk and he need to look down to the screen. if the same user taking a photo over his head means how to find it.

Is there is any sensors we need to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct sensor in iPhone that can recognise where your eyes looking but you can use front camera & machine learning to achieve your functionality. For more refer [recognize gaze direction](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/537891/virtual-eyes-train-deep-learning-algorithm-to-recognize-gaze-direction/)

Comment: Can I use accelerometer or gyro sensors to find the angle and find out the how much the mobile tilted something? is there any way?

Comment: Mostly people while looking at there phone they move there eyes and does not tilt the phone so I don't think accelerometer or gyroscope will help you much